# Delete all visual studio user settings and extensions

Tags: c#, visual-studio, debugging, visual-studio-2017, keyboard-shortcuts

I have following problems with visual studio 2017.
F11 key doesn't mean Step into in when debugging. It instead switches to fullscreen.
shift F11 doesn't Go out when debugging.
Ctrl+R,R doesn't start refractor.
Probably many of other keyboard shorcuts are mapped in different way.
My question how to return visual studio to original state? How do I get back original default keyboard shortcuts?

What I already tried:

1. Deleting some extensions. (As I suspect that some extension caused this behavior)
2. Starting Visual studio installer and clicking repair
   (This looked hopefully. It did change visual studio from dark theme to light theme but after few seconds after starting visual studio everything changed to dark theme again and vertical scrollbar changed back again to map mode, line in the broken version I had previously.)
3. Starting visual studio installer again and clicking uninstall and then after uninstalling visual studio I clicked in the installer the "install" button.
   After the visual studio was freshly installed after few seconds in the IDE the light theme changed to dark. Normal scrollbar changed to map mode.
4. I tried to repeat steps 1-3 several times I tried to revert windows back using recovery point. Unfortunately I don't have old enough recovery point.

Ctrl+R,R somehow started working, but other keyboard shortcuts are still strange.

I believe that some user settings like my name and last name and licence are kept between re-installs. How do I delete everything? Or how do I get old keyboard shortcuts back?

Comment: At the risk of making a dumb/obvious comment, have you confirmed that you have Function Lock enabled?

Comment: If you go to [keyboard shortcut settings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5zwses53.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396), you should be able to tell what plugin is interfering with your shortcuts from `already used by` field. You could also try to restore default key maps.

Comment: @JustinasMarozas You are right. Restoring default keymap did really work.   Thanks. However I still don't understand how it is possible that reinstalling Visual Studio did not reset the key map.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey you can reset all key mappings using:
Tools -> Options -> Environment -> Keyboard -> Select default in the dropdown at the top and click reset